# Passing variable value from android activity to python script

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

Is it possible to pass variable value from activity to python.
I am having file duration,i want to pass it to python script and set Monkeyrunner.sleep(fileduration) in my script.

how can i be able to do that.

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

You should use some method to communicate from your `Activity` to your python script. It would be possible to create a [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) and then invoke it from inside your `Activity` passing the desired value.
Files could also be used as a rudimentary form of communication.